# react-slick overlap navbar dropdown. how can i show dropdown over the slick slider?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, z-index, react-slick

[I'm trying to show navbar dropdown over the slick slider. it's only show when i style .slick-slider z-index negative value, but this is not right because i can't click inside slider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9iuR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a className in your dropdown menu with attribute "z-index:1000".
For example..

```
<div className="dropdown-menu">...</div>
```

on your .css file

```
.dropdown-menu{
  ...          //another attributes for your div and finally..
  z-index:1000
}
```

Comment: not working with bootstrap 3